# How to view SchDoc files online?

Tags: schematics, altium

I have a file witch was designed with "Altium Designer". How could i view this file without needing to install "Altium Designer"? it is preferred to do this with an online app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any.

If you are just viewing a file, you could install Altium Design Viewer.